# padding an int value from SQL

Tags: php, css, sql, sorting

I want to use padding on some INT return values I get from my SQL database, but how do I do that? Can I style it with css in a div tag?

Some specific numbers have to have `padding-left: 20px;` and some specific numbers have to have `padding-right 20px;`. So the problem is that I cannot just use a normal styling. I was thinking there could be an if statement that could sort the numbers?

Comment: why don't you add the padding in your html or php template depending on the value of the int ?? What is your wished output and what did you manage to do until now ? Do you have some code to show ?

Comment: can you give an example? css & SQL usually do not go together, unless you just want some kind of identifier for some values from the DB

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It was a broad question, but Petkos answer nailed it for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very broad, but I will try to answer.
You have tagged it PHP, so I assume you are using some PHP code to output the results. In that case, you can obviously use an `if` statement to set the style. Something like this:

```
<?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>
<div style="<?php 
    if(condition1) echo('padding-left: 20px');
    elseif(condition2) echo('padding-right: 20px'); 
?>">
<?php echo $row['number']; ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Hello Petko. Thanks a lot for your suggestion, it is working for me. I know it was very broad without any code, but you nailed it :) thanks a lot